# How to fix CSV structure?

Tags: csv

I have a CSV text file that is causing me a headache. The file itself is quiet big. Below is a sample of the file and the problem within it. The carriage returns in the comment section are breaking the CSV structure and cause an issue during an import of data in Excel. How do I fix this?

```
"DataId"    "mpi_id"    "pt_enct_no"    "DataElementId" "DataValue" "CreateDate"    "Active"    "CreateBy"
"1675167619"    "205346"    "7" "730"   "N" "5/10/2017 12:12:45 AM" "Y" "cry6707 "
"1675167620"    "205346"    "7" "733"   "N" "5/10/2017 12:12:45 AM" "Y" "cry6707 "
"1675167621"    "205346"    "7" "734"   "N" "5/10/2017 12:12:45 AM" "Y" "cry6707 "
"1675167622"    "205346"    "7" "739"   "N" "5/10/2017 12:12:45 AM" "Y" "cry6707 "
"1675167623"    "205346"    "7" "741"   "8" "5/10/2017 12:12:45 AM" "Y" "cry6707 "
"1675167624"    "205346"    "7" "732"   "Patient glasgow coma scale is 13 or greater.  "    "5/10/2017 12:12:45 AM" "Y" "cry6707 "
"1675167625"    "205346"    "7" "731"   "No facial asymmetry/weakness noted.

"   "5/10/2017 12:12:45 AM" "Y" "cry6707 "
"1675167626"    "205346"    "7" "735"   "No lingual asymmetry/weakness noted.
"   "5/10/2017 12:12:45 AM" "Y" "cry6707 "
"1675167627"    "205346"    "7" "740"   "No palatal asymmetry/weakness noted.

"   "5/10/2017 12:12:45 AM" "Y" "cry6707 "
"1675167628"    "205346"    "7" "736"   "Patient passed the Dysphagia Screening.
Patient glasgow coma scale is 13 or greater.

 No facial asymmetry/weakness noted. No lingual asymmetry/weakness noted. No palatal asymmetry/weakness noted.  
"   "5/10/2017 12:12:45 AM" "Y" "cry6707 "
```

Answer (score 0):

Open your csv file in a text editor like Notepad++ or SublimeText, and replace the newline(s) by a character not present in your file, like `|` for example. Then you will be able to open it in Excel without structure problem.

Comment: I don't have these apps and I can't install them.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for this problem. Instead of importing the file into Excel first, I imported it into Access first and then exported it to Excel, making sure that long comments field is defined as a Long Text field. It worked like a charm.